# How do I trace ISPs in Traceroute?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I used traceroute in windows like below. 
How do I find if the one is in the same ISP or not? 
Please help me find how many ISPs I have passed.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert www.google.com

www.google.com [172.217.31.164]:

  1     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  172.30.1.254
  2     4 ms     5 ms     3 ms  221.158.118.1
  3     5 ms     4 ms     5 ms  59.27.94.93
  4     5 ms     8 ms     6 ms  61.78.45.77
  5     5 ms     6 ms     5 ms  112.188.145.69
  6     *        *        *     
  7     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  112.174.47.178
  8    35 ms    36 ms    36 ms  74.125.52.16
  9    35 ms    35 ms    36 ms  108.170.242.129
 10    38 ms    38 ms    39 ms  209.85.253.109
 11    37 ms    37 ms    38 ms  nrt12s22-in-f4.1e100.net [172.217.31.164]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using something like [mtr](https://github.com/traviscross/mtr) instead of traceroute. You can use a parameter to show [ASNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) traversed, which is basically what you're looking for.

`-z, --aslookup             display AS number`

```
# mtr -zrnc5 google.com
Start: 2020-04-05T17:14:54+0000
HOST: summit                      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
@Not a TXT record
  1. AS???    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      0.0%     5    0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.0
  2. AS7922   96.120.12.41         0.0%     5    9.4   9.0   8.3   9.6   0.6
  3. AS7922   68.85.221.193        0.0%     5   13.4  11.6   9.0  15.9   3.0
  4. AS7922   68.86.128.241        0.0%     5   22.8  18.2  10.2  27.8   7.7
  5. AS7922   68.86.92.121         0.0%     5   13.9  12.3  11.2  13.9   1.2
  6. AS7922   68.86.83.94          0.0%     5   13.1  11.6  10.2  13.1   1.1
  7. AS7922   50.248.118.30        0.0%     5   12.4  14.2  10.4  26.5   7.0
  8. AS15169  108.170.254.81       0.0%     5   19.3  14.1  12.8  19.3   2.9
  9. AS15169  72.14.238.207        0.0%     5   11.1  11.6  10.8  12.1   0.6
 10. AS15169  172.217.1.206        0.0%     5   12.4  11.3  10.1  12.5   1.1
```